# Вычислить значение в отдельном процессе

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - есть код, который создаёт 6 процессов и через канал передает родительскому процессу объекты, при этом значение выражения `2 ** 320000` вычисляется не в порожденных процессах, а в родительском.

Как можно это сделать в дочернем процессе, а в родительский передать результат?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def child(pipe, no):
    for i in range(5):
        #str(2 ** 320000) # Так вычисляет в дочернем процессе
        pipe.send([no, i, 2 ** 320000])
    pipe.send('done')
    pipe.close()
    print('child %s close pipe' % no)


def parent():
    procs = 6
    pipes = []
    for i in range(procs):
        parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        process = Process(target=child, args=(child_pipe, i))
        pipes.append((parent_pipe, child_pipe))
        process.start()

    exit_flag = [False] * procs

    while False in exit_flag:
        for pipe in pipes:

            index = pipes.index(pipe)
            if exit_flag[index]:
                continue

            data = pipe[0].recv()
            if data == 'done':
                exit_flag[index] = True
                continue
            print('parent got: %s' % data)
    print('parent exiting...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

Comment: как определили что процесс родительский это считает?

Comment: по нагрузке в htop, загружается одно ядро из 4. Если раскомментировать #str(2 ** 320000) и запустить код, то загружаются все ядра процессора

Comment: возможно ли что питон посчитал это выражение в дочке один раз и закешировал ответ?

Comment: родительский процесс высчитывает эти значения т.к отрабатывает долго и выводит это число, нагрузка со стороны этого процесса проверил (os.getpid())

Comment: складывается впечатление что пайтон вычисляет значение только в момент обращения к нему... то есть a = 1 + 1 в памяти хранит не значение 2 а именно выражение 1 + 1...

Comment: Сюрприз, сюрприз! Питон -- интерпретатор. Ну, а вашу проблему можно решить передачей только степени, а в дочернем процессе уже считать, хотя странно, степень двойки -- это всего лишь установка бита в очень большом числе, не должно быть долго.